# Is there a standard for embedding JSON in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, inline, dot.js

I would like to embed JSON in HTML. The most elegant solution I have found makes use of the `script`-tag and the mime media type `application/json`.

```
<script id="data" type="application/json">
    {
        "foo" : "bar"
    }
</script>
```

Is this the standard way of embedding JSON? If not, are there any risks with the above solution?

Reasons for using inline JSON (instead of a JSON-P service):

- Small amounts of JSON-data
- Less HTTP-requests
- Preference for inline-JSON to data in HTML-attributes

**[UPDATE]** Reason for embedding json.

I have a gallery widget for a website with very high traffic. The gallery can consist of a 100 images or more. I am only showing one image at a time and the rest of the images will be lazy loaded. However the information (image src) to all images will be rendered in the html on page load. There are various ways to render the image information in the html. Instead of using JSON I could also use html data attributes as shown below:

```
<li class="image" data-src="image-path.jpg">
    <!-- image tag will be created here using javascript -->
</li>
```

Will result in:

```
<li class="image image-loaded" data-src="image-path.jpg">
    <img src="image-path.jpg" />
</li>
```

The disadvantage with the above solution is the extra markup. I would rather use JSON and a Javascript-Templating engine such as [doT.js](http://olado.github.com/doT/tutorial.html#intro).

Comment: What are you going to do with the json your are "embedding"?

Comment: You're better off storing the json as an object in javascript. There is no reason to have embedded json, unless you're somehow going to avoid using javascript to access that json again.

Comment: JSON is a method for transferring data. It's not something that should be used for its own sake. Especially when you're dealing with JavaScript, there's practically no reason to prefer JSON (JavaScript **Object Notation**) over actual JavaScript objects.

Comment: Is it static content you want to embed? Or would you serve the HTML files prepopulated with the embedded JSON? Otherwise I don't see any advantage to embed the JSON directly in HTML

Comment: @PeeHaa: I have updated my question with a reason.

Comment: @Horo: Yes, there is a reason. I don't like mixing data and logic (model and controller). I also don't like mixing data and html (model and view), but this is the situation now.

Comment: @Juhana: JSON is **not** a method. It is a lightweight data-interchange format.

Comment: @mokane: Yes, it's static content and I agree with you.

Comment: @TJ. I didn't mean "method" as a programming term, only as a synonym for "means".

Comment: @Juhana: Ok, I see. But I mention in my question that [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) is not an option. Of course JSON is awesome for transferring data.

Comment: @TJ.: Why is JSONP not an option? Just make it inline-JSON-P :-)

Comment: @Bergi: See my comment to your answer below, you are right and I was on Mars.

Comment: On my department every user have to use chrome. And i am embedding json strings directly into elements values. Some how double quotes doesn't make trouble. I mean no errors. Also i transfer-update these embedded values (json type) to server with AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reasons for using inline JSON (instead of a JSON-P service)

You can inline JSON-P as well. OK, you just call that method "inline script", but it has the advantages of both :-)

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I don't need JSON-P when using JSON inline.

Comment: With JavaScript object literals, you a) don't need `JSON.parse` etc. b) can use `Date` objects and similar non-JSON things c) can directly append the gallery code (instead of separate `<script>` elements) d) don't need to wait for DOMready to extract the JSON

Comment: a) and b) make sense, although I'm just receiving plain text data, so b) doesn't worry me. Could you explain c) I'm not sure I understand correctly? d) is no issue, since Javascript execution begins only when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I was sleeping when I added my first comment to your answer. Not having to use JSON.parse is a plus and I can do that if I assign the JSON to a global variable, similar to JSON-P.

Comment: And using JSON-P makes my main question almost irrelevant :-)

Comment: Giving you the credit. I have also added [an answer with an example further below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14524204/315260).

Answer (score 8):

What you suggest is absolutely correct. The `type` attributes of the `script` tag must be a valid MIME descriptor. According to [the official JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) section 6 "IANA Considerations":

> The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json.
> Type name: application
> Subtype name: json

So your HTML is valid:

```
<script id="data" type="application/json">
    {
        "foo" : "bar"
    }
</script>
```

And, no, there are no additional risks involved in doing this.

Comment: Please read http://benalpert.com/2012/08/03/preventing-xss-json.html for a possible XSS vector.

Comment: @TomMcKenzie Right, that is a risk that pertains to any user-generated content. I assumed that OP generates a `json` file that is safe for consumption to begin with.

Comment: and how can I fetch this?

Comment: @vincentthorpe you don't `fetch` it (`fetch` in this context means that you download data that you don't already have). Instead, you can just access it via DOM selector. E.g. in the example above: `document.querySelector('#data')` (because the `script` tag has `id="data"` ).

Answer (score 5):

I am answering my own question since I have had to find a solution. My solution is based on what **Bergi** suggested using inline JSONP. It is a better solution than finding an answer to my actual question since no manual JSON-parsing is required.

The JSON-data (and HTML) is generated with Java Server Pages (JSP).

**Step 1**

A custom variable name is created using JSP. It will be used as the javascript global variable to which the json data will be assigned to. The name is randomly generated to prevent naming conflicts on the same page.

```
<c:set var="jsonpVarName">jsnpData<%= java.lang.Math.round(java.lang.Math.random() * 1000000) %></c:set>
```

**Step 2**
The script tag has a cssClassname to identify it by and a `data-var`-attribute, so that the custom variable name can be determined. `${ctrl.json}`is JSP and prints out JSON. Unlike JSONP which uses a callback-Function, a global variable is used. So far I have not experienced any drawbacks.

```
<script class="data" data-var="${jsonpVarName}" type="text/javascript">
    window.${jsonpVarName} = ${ctrl.json};
</script>
```

**Step 3**
Accessing the data (using jQuery) is as easy as:

```
var data = window[$('script.data').data('var')];
```

**Example with context**

**HTML**

```
<div class="myWidget">
    <button class="fetchData">Fetch Data</button>


    <c:set var="jsonpVarName">jsnpData<%= java.lang.Math.round(java.lang.Math.random() * 1000000) %></c:set>

    <script class="data" data-var="${jsonpVarName}" type="text/javascript">
        window.${jsonpVarName} = ${ctrl.json};
    </script>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('button.fetchData', '.myWidget').click(function (e) {

    var data = window[$('script.data', '.myWidget').data('var')];    

});
```

I'm using inline JSONP to load JSON-data which is required on page load. It isn't a lot of data and it's one HTTP-Request less.

Answer (score -1):

try http://json2html.com/  that's a good way to Transform JSON to HTML.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question

Comment: I believe that mahmoud is saying use a templating engine like json2html to dynamically convert your JSON feed into html WHEN you need it.  So do something like this .. embed the JSON inside a nice script tag during your server page load then use json2html to convert images (when needed) into actual 'img' elements.