# class="init" meaning inside <script></script> declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've come across the following code for Datatables jquery plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
</script>
```

What is the purpose of class="init" ??

Comment: Who knows... Look in the css maybe?

Comment: Maybe it's for selecting certain scripts? @elclanrs Scripts wouldn't show anyways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506610/is-there-a-benefit-to-putting-a-class-on-a-script-tag

Comment: How can you apply css style to a script inclusion???

Comment: @dendini Using a class, duh. Or the `style` attribute. `<style>` is an element like any other, it's just hidden by default. You can even add a `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: tag of script cannot have class attribute  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Comment: Please note that w3schools is not an authority. It would be better to link to the actual spec.

Comment: In HTML5, `<script>` supports Global Attributes (e.g. `class`). It IS valid in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just invalidates your code.

`class` is not allowed on script, in HTML4 and XHTML.

Although it IS valid in HTML5, as the `<script>` tag supports global attributes (which includes `class`).

[Check out the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

Answer (score 1):

You can select that `script` tag just like any other tag in DOM. Purpose? From CSS "visualization" where code block is, to JS/jQuery dynamic code generation.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere it could be used is dynamically selecting one from many script snippets to use elsewhere.
Like javascript templating language

```
<script class="say_hello english" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
</script>
<script class="say_hello german" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <p>Hallo {{name}}</p>
</script>

...

var say_hello_template = Handlebars.compile($('script.say_hello.' + language).html()); 
$('#header').append(say_hello_template(user));
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In the javascript file, which you have included using tag like `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init" src="../../js/jFile.js"></script>` may contains the coding which refers to the class **init**. This type of class seems like a CSS coding, but it is a reference to javascript.

Open the javascript in a text editor and search for the term "init". The coding may also be defined as mentioned in the article [Is there a benefit to putting a class on a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506610/is-there-a-benefit-to-putting-a-class-on-a-script-tag)